# Migrating from Google Firebase Realtime DB record changes subscription events to AWS Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-dynamodb

I'm migrating an javascript frontend app from a Firebase Realtime DB to a AWS Dynamo DB.

On of the features I used most in Firebase Realtime DB Is the ability to be notified from the Firebase when a record, which I have been subscribed for, changes. But I didn't found anything about it on DynamoDB documentation.

How can I get this same behaviour (or an workaroud to it) with Dynamo DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at "AWS AppSync" first.

If you want to stay with DynamoDB you can use DynamoDB Streams to trigger an event on update and send a message to the client via SNS.